# Visual Studio often just loses all object references

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Fairly often (2 to three times in a work day) my visual studio is going along just fine, but then all of a sudden after running a debug it loses all object references and every line will have that squiggly red line underneath.
[image]

The error list goes nuts along with it basically telling me things like **'Empty' is not a member of 'String'** - basically telling me that none of the classes and objects have any valid properties or methods.

[image]

...every object in the project is now invalid.
OK - it's an easy fix, *close and reopen the project/solution*. This is getting old though.
Has anyone else experienced this behavior?  Any ideas what I might need to change to stop it?

While closing and reopening the solution is easy enough - doing this several times a day is getting annoying...

Comment: I've had a similar issue happen due to nuget restores, but usually a simple build will resolve them all.  I assume nothing with nuget is happening though when you experience this?

Comment: I have several libs installed through Nuget, but I've never been working in the nuget manager or directly with any of the nuget provided libs when this happens.